# MS Access Converting centimeter or millimeter to Inches

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report, data-conversion

The Problem:

Our employees are most of the time buying stuff in Inches and cm/mm, and our customers operate mostly in Inches, which make some unnecessary misunderstandings. So, I need a way to convert the CM into the Inches and the fraction of inches. The problem is by the way perfectly described in this linked video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SQswYo4mbM

What I have:

I have one table converting from Metric to Imperial called “tbl_0_Imperial_Metric”.

[image]

The first column is a primary key auto number record ID, the second column is a short text for the inches and fractions, the third and fourth columns are Double numbers where the inches are represented as cm and mm, and the fifth column is used when the select the inches in a form based on 2 combo boxes.
The other way is solved already by selecting the inches and fraction of inches on the form. As in the example below, the employees select 3 ¼ Inches by selecting ID 20 and 5 from the table, and this is added up and rounded to 83 mm.

[image]

What I need:
A way to convert as in the example above 83 mm to 3 ¼ inches in Access VBA. (Decimal values are not durable, as described earlier and in the video.)
I need to look up the nearest LOWER value to 83 mm in the table, which again would be ID 20 and 76.2 mm, and leave the variance 6.8 (83-76.2=6.8) to look up the nearest fraction of an inch LOWER or HIGHER, which in this case is 6.35 mm accordingly ID 5.

Thanks in advance for a way or solution. ;-)

Comment: I think your problem is using staff that can't do simple arithmetic rather than a VBA issue.

Comment: What do require?  is it a parameterized query (parameter being mm) that returns a single row single text column with the inches from the table?

Comment: @freeflow What a great response. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Glad you approve.  Another suggestion I'd make is that your life will be a lot easier if your dialog box for input had two fields for the fraction  and placed them as they would be seen for a fraction.

Comment: It sound like you will accept @Gustav's solution;  but I thought you were asking for mm to inches conversion, and only by using the fractions available in your table.

Comment: @tinazmu I need some time to study Gustav's response first. But you are right, the smallest fraction we are working with is a 1/16 inch. By the way, I have not responded to Gustav's input yet. But if there are better solutions to my problem, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to convert mms to inches (text) with fractions, you can use a VBA function like:

```
Public Function MM2InchText(sMm As Single) As String
   Dim iInch As Integer, iNom As Integer, iBestNom As Integer, iDenom As Integer, _
       sMmLeft As Single, iBestDenom As Integer, sMinError As Single, _
       sThisError As Single
   
   iInch = Int(sMm / 25.4)
   sMmLeft = sMm - iInch * 25.4
   sMinError = 99
   iDenom = 16
   While iDenom > 1
        iNom = Round(sMmLeft / 25.4 * iDenom)
        sThisError = Abs(sMmLeft - (iNom * (25.4 / iDenom)))
        If sThisError < sMinError Then
          sMinError = sThisError
          iBestNom = iNom
          iBestDenom = iDenom
        End If
        iDenom = iDenom / 2
   Wend
   If iBestNom Mod 2 = 0 Then
        iBestNom = iBestNom / 2
        iBestDenom = iBestDenom / 2
        If iBestNom Mod 2 = 0 Then
            iBestNom = iBestNom / 2
            iBestDenom = iBestDenom / 2
        End If
   End If
   MM2InchText = IIf(iInch = 0, "", CStr(iInch) & " ") & IIf(iBestNom = 0, "", " " & CStr(iBestNom) & "/" & CStr(iBestDenom)) & """"
End Function
```

You can call the function from other VBA code, from SQL queries/forms, using something like (to print to immediate window)

```
debug.print MM2InchText(83)
```

prints:
3  1/4"

Update 2022-03-20: Added an error-size check loop, to get around the problem reported.

Comment: WOW, this is really close to what we need, and a much more efficient solution than I was planning to do, but I think there is a tiny problem with the way it chooses the nearest fraction. 
1/16 inch is 1.5875 mm
1/8" inch is 3.175 mm.
When I call the function with 3 mm I get 1/16" inch, but 3 is closer to 1/8" inch. I actually do not get a 1/8" inch before I call the function with in 3.5 mm.

https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/length/mm-to-inch.html

That's one reason NASA lost a $ 327 million mission to Mars :-) https://www.simscale.com/blog/2017/12/nasa-mars-climate-orbiter-metric/

Comment: Thanks @LasseStaalung, I updated it to loop through the 2/4/8/16 values and choose the one with the smallest error. Let me/us know. And, thanks, I learned something!

Comment: I also changed the Mms parameter to single, realising that you might be using fractional mms.

Comment: Thank You @tinazmu this looks like it's going to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, the inches must be parsed to obtain a decimal value:

```vb
Inches = "3"" 1/4"""
DecimalInches = ParseFeetInches(Inches)
? DecimalInches 
 3.25
```

Next, convert to millimeters:

```vb
Millimeters = MeterInch(DecimalInches) * 1000
? Millimeters
 82.55
```

Finally, round up:

```vb
IntegerMillimeters = RoundUp(Millimeters) 
? IntegerMillimeters 
 83
```

The functions, where you will notice the intense use of data type Decimal to keep an extreme precision:

```vb
' Parse a string for a value of feet and/or inches.
' The inch part can contain a fraction or be decimal.
' Returns the parsed values as decimal inches.
' For unparsable expressions, zero is returned.
'
' Maximum returned value is +/- 7922816299999618530273437599.
' Negative values will only be read as such, if the first
' non-space character is a minus sign.
'
' Smallest reliably parsed value is the fraction 1/2097152
' or the decimal value 0.000000476837158203125.
'
' Requires when not used in Access, for example Excel,
' either:
'   Module Access
' or a reference to Access, for example for Access 2016:
'   Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
'
' 2018-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function ParseFeetInches( _
    ByVal Expression As String) _
    As Variant
    
    Dim ReplaceSets(20, 1)  As String
    Dim ExpressionParts     As Variant
    Dim ExpressionOneParts  As Variant

    Dim Sign                As Variant
    Dim DecimalInteger      As Variant
    Dim DecimalFraction     As Variant
    Dim DecimalInches       As Variant
    Dim Index               As Integer
    Dim Character           As String
    Dim FeetInches          As String
    Dim ExpressionOne       As String
    Dim ExpressionOneOne    As String
    Dim ExpressionOneTwo    As String
    Dim ExpressionTwo       As String
    Dim Numerator           As Long
    Dim Denominator         As Long

    ' Read sign.
    Sign = Sgn(Val(Expression))
    ' Trim double spacing.
    While InStr(Expression, "  ") > 0
        Expression = Replace(Expression, "  ", " ")
    Wend
    ' Replace foot units.
    ReplaceSets(0, 0) = "feet"
    ReplaceSets(0, 1) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(1, 0) = "foot"
    ReplaceSets(1, 1) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(2, 0) = "ft."
    ReplaceSets(2, 1) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(3, 0) = "ft"
    ReplaceSets(3, 1) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(4, 0) = Chr(SmartSingleQuote)   ' Smart Quote: "’"
    ReplaceSets(4, 1) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(5, 0) = " '"
    ReplaceSets(5, 1) = "'"
    ' Replace inch units.
    ReplaceSets(6, 0) = "inches"
    ReplaceSets(6, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(7, 0) = "inch."
    ReplaceSets(7, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(8, 0) = "inch"
    ReplaceSets(8, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(9, 0) = "in."
    ReplaceSets(9, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(10, 0) = "in"
    ReplaceSets(10, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(11, 0) = Chr(SmartDoubleQuote)  ' Smart Quote: "”"
    ReplaceSets(11, 1) = """"
    ReplaceSets(12, 0) = "''"
    ReplaceSets(12, 1) = """"
    ' Replace decimal separator.
    ReplaceSets(13, 0) = ","
    ReplaceSets(13, 1) = "."
    ' Replace units with operators.
    ReplaceSets(14, 0) = """"
    ReplaceSets(14, 1) = ""
    ReplaceSets(15, 0) = "'"
    ReplaceSets(15, 1) = "*" & CStr(InchesPerFoot) & " "
    ' Remove divider spaces.
    ReplaceSets(16, 0) = " /"
    ReplaceSets(16, 1) = "/"
    ReplaceSets(17, 0) = "/ "
    ReplaceSets(17, 1) = "/"
    ' Replace disturbing characters with neutral operator.
    ReplaceSets(18, 0) = " "
    ReplaceSets(18, 1) = "+"
    ReplaceSets(19, 0) = "-"
    ReplaceSets(19, 1) = "+"
    ReplaceSets(20, 0) = "+"
    ReplaceSets(20, 1) = "+0"
    
    ' Add leading neutral operator.
    Expression = "+0" & Expression
    ' Apply all replace sets.
    For Index = LBound(ReplaceSets, 1) To UBound(ReplaceSets, 1)
        Expression = Replace(Expression, ReplaceSets(Index, 0), ReplaceSets(Index, 1))
    Next
    ' Remove any useless or disturbing character.
    For Index = 1 To Len(Expression)
        Character = Mid(Expression, Index, 1)
        Select Case Character
            Case "0" To "9", "/", "+", "*", "."
                FeetInches = FeetInches & Character
        End Select
    Next
        
    ' For unparsable expressions, return 0.
    On Error GoTo Err_ParseFeetInches
    
    ExpressionParts = Split(FeetInches, "/")
    If UBound(ExpressionParts) = 0 Then
        ' FeetInches holds an integer part only, for example, "+00+038*12+0+05".
        ' Evaluate the cleaned expression as is.
        DecimalInches = Sign * CDec(Eval(FeetInches))
    Else
        ' FeetInches holds, for example, "+00+038*12+0+05+03/2048+0".
        ' For a maximum of decimals, split it into two parts:
        '   ExpressionOne = "+00+038*12+0+05+03"
        '   ExpressionTwo = "2048+0"
        ' or Eval would perform the calculation using Double only.
        ExpressionOne = ExpressionParts(0)
        ExpressionTwo = ExpressionParts(1)
        ' Split ExpressionOne into the integer part and the numerator part.
        ExpressionOneParts = Split(StrReverse(ExpressionOne), "+", 2)
        ' Retrieve the integer part and the numerator part.
        '   ExpressionOneOne = "+00+038*12+0+05"
        '   ExpressionOneTwo = "03"
        ExpressionOneOne = StrReverse(ExpressionOneParts(1))
        ExpressionOneTwo = StrReverse(ExpressionOneParts(0))
        
        ' Extract numerator and denominator.
        If Trim(ExpressionOneOne) = "" Then
            ' No integer expression is present.
            ' Use zero.
            ExpressionOneOne = "0"
        End If
        Numerator = Val(ExpressionOneTwo)
        Denominator = Val(ExpressionTwo)
        
        ' Evaluate the cleaned expression for the integer part.
        DecimalInteger = CDec(Eval(ExpressionOneOne))
        ' Calculate the fraction using CDec to obtain a maximum of decimals.
        If Denominator = 0 Then
            ' Cannot divide by zero.
            ' Return zero.
            DecimalFraction = CDec(0)
        Else
            DecimalFraction = CDec(Numerator) / CDec(Denominator)
        End If
        ' Sum and sign the integer part and the fraction part.
        DecimalInches = Sign * (DecimalInteger + DecimalFraction)
    End If
    
Exit_ParseFeetInches:
    ParseFeetInches = DecimalInches
    Exit Function
    
Err_ParseFeetInches:
    ' Ignore error and return zero.
    DecimalInches = CDec(0)
    Resume Exit_ParseFeetInches
    
End Function
```

```vb
' Converts a value for a measure in inches to meters.
' Returns 0 (zero) for invalid inputs.
'
' Will convert any value within the range of Decimal
' with the precision of Decimal.
' Converts values exceeding the range of Decimal as
' Double.
'
' Largest value with full 28-digit precision is 1E+26
' Smallest value with full 28-digit precision is 1E-24
'
' Examples:
'   Inch = 40.0
'   Meter = MeterInch(Inch)
'   Meter -> 1.016
'
'   Inch = 1 / MetersPerInch            ' Double.
'   Inch -> 39.3700787401575
'   Meter = MeterInch(Inch)
'   Meter -> 1.0000000000000005
'
'   Inch = CDec(1) / MetersPerInch      ' Decimal.
'   Inch -> 39.370078740157480314960629921
'   Meter = MeterInch(Inch)
'   Meter -> 1.0
'
' 2018-04-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MeterInch( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As Variant

    Dim Result  As Variant
    
    If IsNumeric(Value) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Result = CDec(Value) * MetersPerInch
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Decimal overflow.
            ' Calculate without conversion to Decimal.
            Result = CDbl(Value) * MetersPerInch
        End If
    Else
        Result = 0
    End If
    
    MeterInch = Result
    
End Function
```

```vb
' Rounds Value up with count of decimals as specified with parameter NumDigitsAfterDecimal.
'
' Rounds to integer if NumDigitsAfterDecimal is zero.
'
' Optionally, rounds negative values away from zero.
'
' Uses CDec() to prevent bit errors of reals.
'
' Execution time is about 0.5µs for rounding to integer,
' else about 1µs.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundUp( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long, _
    Optional ByVal RoundingAwayFromZero As Boolean) _
    As Variant

    Dim Scaling     As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    
    ' Only round if Value is numeric and ReturnValue can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        If NumDigitsAfterDecimal <> 0 Then
            Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
        Else
            Scaling = 1
        End If
        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for NumDigitsAfterDecimal has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        ElseIf RoundingAwayFromZero = False Or Value > 0 Then
            ' Round numeric value up.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ' Integer rounding.
                ReturnValue = -Int(-Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = -Int(CDec(-Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ScaledValue = -Int(-Value * Scaling)
                    ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Round absolute value up.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ' Integer rounding.
                ReturnValue = Int(Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = Int(CDec(Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ScaledValue = Int(Value * Scaling)
                    ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Double.
            ' Return value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        End If
    End If
    
    RoundUp = ReturnValue

End Function
```

The reverse conversion:

```vb
Millimeters = 83
Inches = InchMeter(Millimeters / 1000)
? Inches
 3.2677165354330708661417322835 

TextInches = FormatFeetInches(Inches, 4, "i r""")
? TextInches
3 1/4"
```

Full code is on **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Full documentation:

[Convert and format imperial distance (feet and inches) with high precision](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31931/Convert-and-format-imperial-distance-feet-and-inches-with-high-precision.html?preview=TbXtlf8IKMA%3D)

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html?preview=9KH3diMD6vc%3D)

and also:

[Round by the power of two](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31859/Round-by-the-power-of-two.html?preview=ncnDzAvJwPY%3D)